# What is the local character given by class field theory?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Dorman's [paper on singular moduli](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01446429.pdf) uses the "local character given by class field theory". Specifically, on page 178, the author states,

> For each prime $p$, finite or infinite, let $\epsilon_p : \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{d}) \to \{\pm 1\}$ be the local character given by class field theory.

I'm familiar with the main statements of class field theory, but I have to admit - I don't know what this character is. Can anyone enlighten me with a reference?

Comment: Should it be $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt d)^\times$?

Comment: In the paper it is $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{d})$, but there are some other typos, so it's possible that there should be a $\times$ up there.